# Заполнение массива от 0 до числа N-1

Tags: c++, массивы

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

std::vector<int> arr(int n = 0) {
  std::cin >> n;
  for (int i=0; i<n-1; i++)
    {
   arr[i]=i;
  }
  for (int i=0; i<=n-1; i++)
    {
   std::cout << arr[i];
  }
}
```

выдаёт следующие ошибки при тесте на сайте:

```
main.cpp:11:4: error: subscript of pointer to function type 'std::vector<int> (int)'
   arr[i]=i;
   ^~~
main.cpp:15:17: error: subscript of pointer to function type 'std::vector<int> (int)'
   std::cout << arr[i] << ",";
                ^~~
2 errors generated.
```

В ide visual studio пишет: для индекса требуется массив или указатель

Пытался так же делать без вектора, обычным массивом, тоже не работает. Задача на https://www.codewars.com/kata/571d42206414b103dc0006a1/train/cpp

Comment: Брр... Тут есть функция `arr`, объяленная как `std::vector<int> arr(int n = 0) {`, и в ее теле вы пытаетесь использовать эту функцию как массив `arr[i]`... Это как?

Comment: я векторным массивом никогда не сталкивался, сделал как думал за правильно. Как я понял, vector<int> arr(int n = 0) это аналог обьявления обычного масива int arr[n];

Comment: Тогда `double sqrt(double x)`, по-вашему, объявление переменной `sqrt`? :) Это объявление (даже определение - дальше идут фигурные скобки) функции `arr`, принимающей параметр типа `int` (со значением по умолчанию 0), и возвращающей вектор `std::vector<int>`.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Заглянул на сайт. Вам надо было всего лишь в своей функции объявить вектор с другим именем, каковой и вернуть:

```
std::vector<int> arr(int n = 0) {
    std::vector<int> a;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        a.push_back(i);
    return a;
}
```

Вы же ничтоже сумняшеся в качестве вектора пытались использовать саму функцию. Для чего она никак не предназначена :)

Comment: просто до этого я сталкивался только с функциями int main() и void main(), а это я воспринял как обьявление массива

Answer (score 0):

Алгоритм написан, нужно  просто его использовать:

```
int n;
std::cin >> n;
std::vector<int> arr(n);
std::iota(arr.begin(), arr.end(), 0);
```